# Guzzle 6 autoload functions.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to update to Guzzle 6 and in the changelog you have this:

> Static functions in **GuzzleHttp\Utils** have been moved to namespaced functions under the **GuzzleHttp** namespace. This requires either a Composer based autoloader or you to include **functions.php**.

Now I have tried different ways of autoloading the functions but I'm getting different errors. What is the proper way of autoloading the functions on composer.json

I have added this to my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php"]
}
```

Then after that I get an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\uri_template()
>   (previously declared in
>   /home/fabio/flubit/dm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:18)
>   in /home/fabio/flubit/dm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php on
>   line 32

So obviously I'm trying to load something that's already being loaded.

So I removed the autoload from composer and then try to use the `json_decode()`built in function on Guzzle doing this `\GuzzleHttp\json_decode()` I get this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\json_decode()

Comment: Are you using the Composer autoloader?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes look at my updated question

Comment: I'd a) remove the "autoload" section you added to `composer.json` (Guzzle already gets loaded automatically, you're probably double-loading it) and if that doesn't fix it b) remove the entire `vendor/` directory and do a fresh `composer install`. Also, Guzzle doesn't have a `json_decode` function - PHP does. `\GuzzleHttp\json_decode()` won't ever work.

Comment: @ceejayoz you are right, the thing was my Phpstorm was doing a search on my repo that has the old version of Guzzle and in there the json_decode() indeed exists, then they changed it do jsonDecode() on version 5 and it seems on guzzle 6 they completely removed. So the problem wasn't on the autoload but in the fact I was looking at the wrong Guzzle version thinking that I was looking at version 6

Answer (score 0):

The Guzzle does provide the 'json' [Request Option](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json) which can simplify the creation of sending json encoded requests.  It will automatically encode using PHP's `json_encode()` function and then set the appropriate content type header.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, but that's not what I was looking for, I was looking for [this function](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/5.3/src/Utils.php#L132) which was removed on v6

Comment: That function is simply a wrapper around PHP's `json_decode()`.  `$json = \json_decode($response->getBody()->__toString())`

Comment: I know and that's why we used that function on our applications because it's a proper way of decoding json throwing an exception when json is wrong.  Nevermind,  we just extracted that function into one of our internal repositories